# Book starting with one of the characters playing Doom 2

Tags: story-identification

This is a long shot, I rented a german book from the library around 16 years ago but only remember some hazy details. I'm fairly sure the book began with the description of one of the characters playing Doom 2 "since 2 hours". He was at some kind of boss, killing him only to be immediately slain by one of its minor monsters. The character is pretty pissed, and enters the IDKFA cheat and "with a smile heard the shotgun clicking in his hands" (rough translation) and then going on a killing-spree in-game.

This is the most I've got, I think at the end of the book he's chasing another character to the top of a tower (?) with a flamethrower. I think he was being drawn in into a fantasy-computer world in his head or something. After the end of the book was some kind of index with a bit of computer-lingo explained, the only entry I remember was "ANSI-Bomb", but I'm not sure this wasn't maybe another book.